# linux get filecontent as stdio after pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I have an linux command that reads stdio and generates a simple file per hour:

```
myapp > ~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" )
```

Then, because myapp can read from stdio clear text files and my input files are zipped, i use zcat to read files and send them to previous processing:

```
zcat myfile.zip | myapp > ~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" )
```

so far, everything is fine. the problem is that i need to read that variable-name file and continue to process it, eg, to send the file content to 'head' command. i try:

```
head $( zcat myfile.zip | myapp > ~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" ) )
```

without sucess. and i really don't want to create another variable because this process can take more than 1h to go.. and maybe i will get a diferent filename variable in head:

```
zcat myfile.zip | myapp > ~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" ) ) && head ~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" )
```

So, what do you think is the best way to do this?

thanks all.

Comment: Perhaps `tee` might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store it first on a variable?

```
FILENAME=$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" )
zcat myfile.zip | myapp > ~/"$FILENAME" && head ~/"$FILENAME"
```

Comment: because if i invoke all this is a cron every hour and each process takes more than 1 hour will have problems because filename variable will be overwriten, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I could read what you mean but FILENAME is only set once and will not change until that line where it gets assigned gets executed again perhaps through loop or if the script gets called again. So the one hat myapp uses and the one that head uses would always be the same. So FILENAME will never change between call of zcat and head. And as Inspired explained as well, each instance of the task won't change the other task since they would run on a different shell. The variable only exist in the shell, not globally on a system.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tee`:

```
zcat myfile.zip | myapp | tee ~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" ) | head
```

Comment: This is not equivalent: in the original code, `head` is started only after (and if) `myapp` finishes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Store the file name in a variable:

```
filename=~/$( date "+%Y%m%d%H.txt" ); zcat myfile.zip | myapp > $filename && head $filename
```

Comment: if i invoke all this is a cron every hour and each process takes more than 1 hour will have problems because filename variable will be overwriten, right?

Comment: No, I suppose that with cron you have a different shell for each job. But there can arise a load problem: if a new process is launched before the previous terminates, it will work slower (as the previous process takes its part of resources) and will exceed the 1-hour slot more than previous, and then the third process will exceed it even more, and then you'll risk a situation when there are three jobs running simultaneously and then four and then you just lose control over them.